# Is there an infinite composite numbers $n$ such that $\sigma(\sigma(n)+n) = 2 \cdot \sigma(n)$

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum

For a positive integer $n$, let $\sigma(n)$ denote the sum of the positive divisors of $n$.

Now, suppose that $n$ is a composite number. Is there an infinitely many $n$ composite such that $\sigma(\sigma(n)+n) = 2\cdot \sigma(n)$?

And in the case where there are an infinitely many $n$ composite such that $\sigma(\sigma(n)+n) = 2\cdot \sigma(n)$, it is conjectured that all numbers composite $n$ satisfying the equation $\sigma(\sigma(n)+n) = 2\cdot \sigma(n)$ are odd (except 2).

See the first 20 values of $n$ found by Peter (there are all odd, except 2).

---

I failed to prove this conjecture in my previous attempt, so I edited this thread.

Comment: It is not true, generally, that $\sigma (ab)=\sigma(a)\sigma (b)$.  That only holds if $\gcd(a,b)=1$.  Try $a=b=3$, for a counterexample to total multiplicativity.

Comment: And it certainly isn't true that $\sigma(ab)=\sigma(a)+\sigma(b)$.

Comment: Post edit:  As my counterexample shows, it is not always possible to write a composite number $n$ as $a\times b$ where $a,b>1$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.  It is true, of course, that you can do that if you exclude the case $n=p^k$ for some prime $p$.

Comment: @lulu : Thanks for your answers. I have edited for $gcd(a,b)=1$ but it seems there are other problems. Almost of this proof is from chatGPT. It is not ready to solve mathematics problems.

Comment: As I say, your edit is incorrect.  ChapGPT has no idea how to do mathematics, it doesn't even try.  All it tries to do is to *sound like* it is doing math.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ChatGPT generated material is not mathematical in nature.

Comment: @lulu: ok I agree for the close. I wanted to test ChatGPT many times but it fails to do math.

Comment: Removing the ChatGPT part is a good start , but a search range upto some reasonable limit , would be another step. This would also immediately reveal that it is not true that no composite $n$ satisfies this equation. The first $20$ solutions are $$[329, 413, 623, 869, 979, 1819, 2585, 3107, 3173, 3197, 3887, 4235, 4997, 5771, 6149, 6187, 6443, 7409, 8399, 8759]$$ The question itself would be interesting (and not at all trivial, perhaps even out of reach).

Comment: Upto $n=10^7$ , there are $313$ solutions.

Comment: Upto $n=10^9$ , there are $1804$ solutions.

Comment: I just edited because the question seems to be interesting when I deleted the "proof" found by chatGPT.

Comment: Peter, could you give other values ($10^5$, $10^6$, $10^8$ ...)

Comment: Upto $10^5,10^6,10^7,10^8,10^9$ there are $50,131,313,746,1804$ solutions respectively. I wonder whether there is an even solution (except $2$).

Comment: Results seems to be very 'predictible' : $ln(y) = 0.387 ln(x) -0.508$ , with very small deviation. If the next values confirm this tendance ($4458$ for $10^{10}$, $10868$ for $10^{11}$), we can conjecture something. But last 2 points are under this regression-formula, so ...

Comment: @Peter: thanks for your work, your conjecture is interesting, so I edited my message to include your conjecture. I also post to correct one error in the text of the bounty (I can't edit it now). So the first conjecture is: are there many infinitely composite $n$ such that $\sigma(\sigma(n)+n) = 2 \cdot \sigma(n)$? So in the case where $n$ is not prime, the case where $n$ is prime is obvious. The second conjecture is "are there only composite odd $n$ satisfying the previous equation?" To conclude, we don't work with prime numbers but we focus on composite $n$.

Comment: @CrawCraw Strictly speaking , we do not know whether infinite many Sophie-Germain primes exist , but this is extremely likely. We need such a heuristic (a probably infinite family) for the composite case as well.

Comment: @Peter do you mean that our conjectures are a particular case of the Sophie-Germain?

Comment: @CrawCraw No, I just wanted to point out that it is not proven that there are infinite many prime solutions. Because a prime $n$ is a solution iff it is a Sophie-Germain prime. We do not actually know that there are infinite many, but we can safely assume it. So, you are right that the prime case is (almost) solved.

Comment: The good news is that the [Schinzel hypothesis](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchinzelsHypothesis.html) implies that there are also infinite many composite solutions : Let $k$ be a positive integer and $[a,b,c,d]=[8k-1,48k-1,24k-1,32k-1]$. If $a,b,c,d$ are simultaneously prime, then $n=ab$ is a composite solution. And the mentioned hypothesis is that we can find infinite many such positive integers $k$.

Comment: $n=p(6p+5)$ is a composite solution if $p$ is an odd prime number such that $3p+2,4p+3,6p+5$ are primes. I don't know if there are infinitely many such primes $p$.