# Is $n=2$ the only even solution of $\sigma(\sigma(n)+n)=2\sigma(n)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, prime-factorization, divisor-sum

Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4651340/82961)
question.

For positive integer $m$ , let $\sigma(m)$ be the divisor-sum function.

Let $S$ be the set of positive integers $n$ satisfying $$\sigma(\sigma(n)+n)=2\sigma(n)$$ In the linked question, $n$ is assumed to be composite and it is asked whether there are still infinite many solutions.

For a prime number $n$ we have $$n\in S\iff 2n+1\ is\ prime$$ in other words a prime is in $S$ iff it is a Sophie-Germain prime.

Question $1$ : Has $S$ only one even entry ($n=2$) ? Upto $n=10^9$ , there are $1804$ composite solutions , all odd.

Question $2$ : If we demand $n$ to be non-squarefree that is there is a prime $p$ with $p^2\mid n$. Are there still infinite many numbers in $S$ ?

Upto $n=10^9$ , there are $91$ such solutions :

```
1  3887    [13, 2; 23, 1]
2  4235    [5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 2]
3  18515    [5, 1; 7, 1; 23, 2]
4  21413    [7, 2; 19, 1; 23, 1]
5  64325    [5, 2; 31, 1; 83, 1]
6  94259    [11, 2; 19, 1; 41, 1]
7  135641    [11, 2; 19, 1; 59, 1]
8  203203    [7, 2; 11, 1; 13, 1; 29, 1]
9  444125    [5, 3; 11, 1; 17, 1; 19, 1]
10  638911    [7, 2; 13, 1; 17, 1; 59, 1]
11  721039    [11, 2; 59, 1; 101, 1]
12  979825    [5, 2; 7, 1; 11, 1; 509, 1]
13  1303533    [3, 4; 7, 1; 11, 2; 19, 1]
14  2452307    [11, 2; 13, 1; 1559, 1]
15  2774893    [11, 2; 17, 1; 19, 1; 71, 1]
16  3986983    [7, 2; 11, 1; 13, 1; 569, 1]
17  4670827    [7, 2; 19, 1; 29, 1; 173, 1]
18  5937505    [5, 1; 7, 1; 17, 2; 587, 1]
19  6242845    [5, 1; 7, 2; 83, 1; 307, 1]
20  6524203    [7, 3; 23, 1; 827, 1]
21  7784775    [3, 3; 5, 2; 19, 1; 607, 1]
22  8165443    [11, 2; 13, 1; 29, 1; 179, 1]
23  9541571    [13, 3; 43, 1; 101, 1]
24  12855323    [13, 2; 29, 1; 43, 1; 61, 1]
25  15982075    [5, 2; 353, 1; 1811, 1]
26  17711785    [5, 1; 7, 2; 13, 1; 67, 1; 83, 1]
27  18333007    [7, 3; 11, 1; 43, 1; 113, 1]
28  25544189    [11, 2; 19, 1; 41, 1; 271, 1]
29  26411245    [5, 1; 7, 2; 23, 1; 43, 1; 109, 1]
30  29018339    [7, 2; 19, 1; 71, 1; 439, 1]
31  38293255    [5, 1; 7, 2; 11, 1; 13, 1; 1093, 1]
32  47075975    [5, 2; 17, 1; 257, 1; 431, 1]
33  47975075    [5, 2; 313, 1; 6131, 1]
34  55225825    [5, 2; 311, 1; 7103, 1]
35  56455399    [7, 3; 11, 1; 13, 1; 1151, 1]
36  57070525    [5, 2; 971, 1; 2351, 1]
37  57417041    [11, 2; 17, 1; 103, 1; 271, 1]
38  63920255    [5, 1; 7, 2; 17, 1; 103, 1; 149, 1]
39  76815775    [5, 2; 17, 1; 61, 1; 2963, 1]
40  77492393    [11, 2; 19, 1; 37, 1; 911, 1]
41  93993209    [19, 2; 31, 1; 37, 1; 227, 1]
42  94270463    [7, 5; 71, 1; 79, 1]
43  100735375    [5, 3; 13, 1; 61991, 1]
44  100786829    [11, 2; 13, 1; 17, 1; 3769, 1]
45  118049869    [7, 2; 19, 1; 23, 1; 37, 1; 149, 1]
46  121619825    [5, 2; 73, 1; 103, 1; 647, 1]
47  145022449    [11, 1; 13, 2; 181, 1; 431, 1]
48  147370685    [5, 1; 7, 2; 11, 1; 149, 1; 367, 1]
49  171094999    [23, 2; 281, 1; 1151, 1]
50  171254125    [5, 3; 7, 1; 19, 1; 10301, 1]
51  171667727    [7, 3; 11, 1; 173, 1; 263, 1]
52  196033409    [11, 1; 13, 2; 17, 1; 6203, 1]
53  205750571    [13, 2; 23, 1; 43, 1; 1231, 1]
54  237542689    [23, 2; 191, 1; 2351, 1]
55  246804943    [7, 1; 11, 1; 47, 2; 1451, 1]
56  252986195    [5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 2; 31, 1; 41, 1; 47, 1]
57  269806201    [7, 3; 17, 1; 46271, 1]
58  272101201    [17, 1; 23, 2; 79, 1; 383, 1]
59  294272605    [5, 1; 11, 2; 503, 1; 967, 1]
60  296686425    [3, 1; 5, 2; 7, 3; 19, 1; 607, 1]
61  317194493    [7, 2; 11, 1; 19, 1; 47, 1; 659, 1]
62  325791527    [23, 2; 193, 1; 3191, 1]
63  336256011    [3, 2; 7, 1; 13, 1; 151, 1; 2719, 1]
64  347093215    [5, 1; 7, 2; 79, 2; 227, 1]
65  362530025    [5, 2; 11, 1; 13, 1; 23, 1; 4409, 1]
66  393083027    [17, 1; 73, 2; 4339, 1]
67  400341427    [23, 1; 79, 2; 2789, 1]
68  401926175    [5, 2; 7, 2; 328103, 1]
69  413847707    [7, 1; 13, 2; 349829, 1]
70  414045835    [5, 1; 7, 2; 251, 1; 6733, 1]
71  428035685    [5, 1; 7, 1; 11, 2; 53, 1; 1907, 1]
72  485327899    [7, 2; 23, 1; 499, 1; 863, 1]
73  524725565    [5, 1; 7, 2; 13, 2; 19, 1; 23, 1; 29, 1]
74  539167409    [11, 2; 47, 1; 113, 1; 839, 1]
75  559493375    [5, 3; 7, 1; 17, 1; 29, 1; 1297, 1]
76  560044233    [3, 3; 7, 1; 31, 1; 61, 1; 1567, 1]
77  562128853    [11, 2; 13, 1; 191, 1; 1871, 1]
78  630265225    [5, 2; 17, 1; 71, 1; 20887, 1]
79  679338205    [5, 1; 7, 2; 13, 1; 263, 1; 811, 1]
80  691733735    [5, 1; 7, 2; 11, 1; 223, 1; 1151, 1]
81  692317087    [7, 1; 11, 1; 29, 2; 10691, 1]
82  693003227    [7, 2; 29, 1; 173, 1; 2819, 1]
83  711193351    [11, 2; 17, 1; 19, 1; 31, 1; 587, 1]
84  729085063    [7, 2; 31, 1; 89, 1; 5393, 1]
85  752731625    [5, 3; 107, 1; 167, 1; 337, 1]
86  892694803    [7, 1; 11, 2; 13, 1; 17, 1; 19, 1; 251, 1]
87  896928445    [5, 1; 7, 1; 61, 2; 71, 1; 97, 1]
88  942742535    [5, 1; 7, 1; 43, 1; 53, 2; 223, 1]
89  975607721    [11, 1; 23, 2; 389, 1; 431, 1]
90  978386893    [11, 1; 19, 2; 37, 1; 6659, 1]
91  994422871    [13, 2; 17, 1; 23, 1; 101, 1; 149, 1]
```

Question $3$ : If $\sigma(n)$ is odd , so $n=l^2$ or $n=2l^2$ for some positive integer $l$. Is $n=2$ the only solution with this restriction ?

Upto $n=10^{14}$ , the only solution of this form is $2$

Comment: among even $n$  it seems $\sigma(\sigma(n)+n) \leq 2\sigma(n)$  implies $n$  or $2n$ is a square, and there may be an if and only if hanging around.  I see, your question 3 is related

Comment: If $$n=2k$$ with odd $k$, then :$$\sigma(n)=3\sigma(k)$$ and so we get: $$\sigma(3\sigma(k)+2k)=6\sigma(k)$$

Comment: If k were even then we get:$$ n=4j\implies \sigma(n)=7\sigma(j)$$ and therefore $$\sigma(7\sigma(j)+4j)=14\sigma(j)$$